# Libraries for Face Detection

Tags: mobile, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

I need to develop a mobile app (primarily for Android, iOS, and Windows Mobile) for face detection.  Obviously, OpenCV is the most well known.  However, I'm unsure about the compatibility among the different OS'es.  Besies OpenCV, are there other options?  2 key requirements:

-Open source/commercial libraries but must run locally/natively in devices without internet connection so Player Service API would not work

-Capable of tracking multiple faces in motion

Anyone can share their experiences/knowledge in this area? Any pointers greatly appreciated!

Comment: Huh? There's Face Detection and then there's Face Detection.  1) Are you trying to find a face in the image, say for focusing a camera... or 2) are you trying to find a face to recognize a particular emotion or 3) are you trying to identify a particular person by name?  These are dramatically different things.   Look at OpenCV with Python, or roll your own via machine learning techniques. Note: I'd recommend Coursera Machine Learning Class with Andrew Ng.  Fun, and you'd learn a lot.   I will say, this question seems too broad for StackOverflow.

Comment: It may be a bit broad as this is just a POC.  The main goal is to count the number of people passing through a main entrance of an establishment.  So no emotion detection or recognition is necessary at all.

Comment: Ouch.  That's not face detection, that's tracking people and that is a MUCH more difficult algorithm.  You'll find plenty of examples out there, but generally they're using OpenCV and a regular computer. [Here's an example.](http://www.slideshare.net/omidAsudeh/real-time-pedestrian-detection-tracking-and-distance-estimation)  Your's is even going to be harder because you may not have enough room or isolation to show an entire person from head to toe.  And on mobile? Probably not an easy task.

Comment: Good points.  Did think about people tracking but likely where the device will be placed, the best features are the faces or heads.  It appears to me OpenCV can do face detection (out of the box, please correct me if I'm wrong), unsure about the accuracy.  My thought, as long as I can collect a series of "boxes" or rectangles that crop out what appear to be faces,  I can send them to a CNN cluster (probably runs on Caffe, Torch, or Tensorflow) for heavier detection/recognition workloads to determine whether the boxes are faces.

Comment: And another layer is counting the unique faces (should approximate to count of people), probably will require recognition?  I would assume the key here is a reliable way to detect faces (which is the role of the mobile device).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are really pushing the margin a whole lot.

Face detection generally consists of three different areas.
1) Recognizing a face as a face (there is a mouth, a nose, eyes)  This is useful for focusing a snapshot.
2) Recognizing facial features, looking for emotion (mouth in a smile) or eye tracking.
3) Facial recognition. Using the system to perform identification by attaching a name to a face.

You want to use a face recognition tool to perform tracking and count people entering a particular place, using a mobile phone.

First tracking is pretty difficult.  Its one thing to perform simple face identity in a single frame snap shot. That's pretty easy. The problem is, you may find your frame rates so poor that you can only accommodate 1 frame every three or even every five seconds. That will make it nearly impossible to track and count faces.  Counting faces is easy, but what's hard is to determine if that face  in the screen was counted previously or is a new person entering the screen.

OpenCV has a whole lot of tools and examples out there for facial recognition, image tracking, etc.  I'd strongly recommend playing with OpenCV and test its capabilities.  I'd recommend the C/C++ versions (unless you are already a Python programmer)  [Here's a place to start, a blog entry](http://dogfeatherdesign.com/opencv-3-0-microsoft-visual-studio-2015-cmake-and-c/) I wrote a few months ago.

I really like the tutorials from Kyle Hounslow... Look him up on youtube.  His videos are well thought out, they are interesting and he provides example code for all his work.  Go ahead and watch all of those videos, and repeat all of those examples.  Get a feel for what is available in frame rates using a laptop.

The next part of your task is porting stuff from OpenCV to Android/iOS.  That's no easy task.  I'm sure folks have tried, and I'm sure helpful hints are out there.

I don't mean to dissuade you from an awesome investigation but do note what you want to do is mighty difficult.  You will have to invest some time to even determine where all the difficult areas are.  And unfortunately you won't know effective frame rates and performance until you build some stuff and try it.
Good luck with the journey.

Comment: The traffic tracking/counting looks promising.  Is the source open?

Comment: @1001b  unfortunately not that I've been able to find. But there are many many samples out there that can get you close. Start with the single object tracking examples from Kyle Hounslow that will give you the insight you need. Go through all of his examples.